# Request does not match any route in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm getting a “Request does not match any route” error on the product attribute API

URL - `http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/marketplace/productAttribut/get`

**Error Message**

```
{
  ["message"]=>
  string(33) "Request does not match any route."
}
```

Comment: `productAttribut` -> `productAttribute` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the special characters from the product attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here (in addition to the typo pointed out by [@Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812842/robbie-averill)) is that there is no Web API for `module-marketplace`.  You can confirm this by as follows:

- cd to `/vendor/magento/module-marketplace`. Note there is no `etc/webapi.xml` under this directory.
- cd to `/vendor/module-integration`.  See that there **is** an `etc/webapi.xml` under this directory.